# Does the window.screen object include the entire browser window in or just the same inner part of it (web page)

Tags: javascript, browser, window, built-in-types

I want to know if the window.screen object includes the whole screen of the device, including browser window and so on
Or it’s only the demarcated part for web page interaction?
And how different is it from the document object module?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the `window.screen` object:

```
Screen {availWidth: 1920, availHeight: 1040, width: 1920, height: 1080, colorDepth: 24, …}
availHeight: 1040
availLeft: 0
availTop: 0
availWidth: 1920
colorDepth: 24
height: 1080
orientation: ScreenOrientation {angle: 0, type: "landscape-primary", onchange: null}
pixelDepth: 24
width: 1920
__proto__: Screen
```

This is what I've got in my chrome browser. (My Screen is of `1920px/1080px`)

As it's seen, we've got various members of `Screen` including full height, width and also the available ones. `availableHeight` defers for the browser's heading/navigating stuffs.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Comment: Okay so what you’re saying is the screen object can infer to the entire user’s screen or a portion of it depending on the property that’s in use? For example, you can have a full height/width of 1080px/1920px but if it’s the available Height/width property you’re looking for, you’ll have 1040px//1920px?

Comment: yes, you're right available ```height and width```  are the space (it defers from actual height because of browser's location, status, bookmarks, window title, borders, etc)

in general it's still refereed as FHD or 1920/1080 screens, I mean the gap is not considered.